# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut in AdActivity

Tags: android, admob, android-anr-dialog

I received an ANR error report in my Developer console and I could not replicate this issue.

```
ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut in com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity
```

Here is a few from the log I got in my Developer Console:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419289a0 self=0x40090010
| sysTid=5597 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074811868
| state=S schedstat=( 22603587000 4850665501 38135 ) utm=1943 stm=317 core=1
#00 pc 0001770c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002a70d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 0001709d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+44)
#04 pc 000172b7 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+114)
#05 pc 00014a3b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+34)
#06 pc 0004a5a7 /system/lib/libmedia.so
#07 pc 000486f7 /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::MediaPlayer::setDataSource(char const*, android::KeyedVector<android::String8, android::String8> const*)+102)
#08 pc 00012235 /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
#09 pc 0001e290 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#10 pc 0004d411 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
#11 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#13 pc 0005ff07 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
#14 pc 000677e1 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#16 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#17 pc 0005fc31 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#18 pc 000499fb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#19 pc 000468f9 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#20 pc 000475bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
#21 pc 00000db7 /system/bin/app_process
#22 pc 0001271f /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
#23 pc 00000ae8 /system/bin/app_process
at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:958)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:946)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:899)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataCommon(HTML5VideoView.java:234)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoView.java:271)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoInline.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoInline.java:67)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:247)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:381)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-377" prio=5 tid=16 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x434aa530 self=0x684613f0
| sysTid=6184 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1740310048
| state=S schedstat=( 220125 144750 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x434aa690> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=16 (Thread-377)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:248)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.b.run(SourceFile:110)

"Thread-367" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424be9a0 self=0x6548b798
| sysTid=5861 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1699697872
| state=S schedstat=( 614124000 155518500 1137 ) utm=30 stm=31 core=0
#00 pc 0001860c /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 0012b949 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#02 pc 0012b755 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#03 pc 00058415 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#04 pc 00056b13 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::RunInternal()+114)
#05 pc 00056b71 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::Run()+16)
#06 pc 000771d9 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (base::Thread::ThreadMain()+188)
#07 pc 00076c93 /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
#08 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#09 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AdWorker #10" prio=5 tid=24 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42505360 self=0x65513d38
| sysTid=5856 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1693754872
| state=S schedstat=( 5158875 1391625 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42505490> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=24 (AdWorker #10)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=26 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424fba78 self=0x64f9de20
| sysTid=5854 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1700056752
| state=S schedstat=( 5502000 4725750 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x424d4488> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=26 (AsyncTask #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424ed4d8 self=0x64eb9010
| sysTid=5852 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1698324848
| state=S schedstat=( 760875 3061875 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
#00 pc 0001860c /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014b09 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 00014d71 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 0005ee2b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001e290 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004d411 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
#06 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#08 pc 0005fc31 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#09 pc 0005fc5b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#10 pc 000547d7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#12 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:58)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=23 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424dfe28 self=0x65282618
| sysTid=5850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1693304448
| state=S schedstat=( 96815166381 6945372375 34587 ) utm=9350 stm=331 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x43412b38> (a android.webkit.CallbackProxy)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.sendMessageToUiThreadSync(CallbackProxy.java:1612)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:1035)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.handleUrl(BrowserFrame.java:635)
at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:92)
at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:812)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #9" prio=5 tid=22 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x425961c0 self=0x64ed7d90
| sysTid=5837 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1688329088
| state=S schedstat=( 17043000 22746750 69 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x425962f0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=22 (AdWorker #9)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #8" prio=5 tid=21 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423bd030 self=0x652cf248
| sysTid=5836 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1698325648
| state=S schedstat=( 31946625 39978000 119 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4238f148> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=21 (AdWorker #8)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #7" prio=5 tid=20 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4257fbe8 self=0x65cbac58
| sysTid=5832 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1707861064
| state=S schedstat=( 24793875 28706250 108 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4259cda8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=20 (AdWorker #7)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #6" prio=5 tid=19 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42590de0 self=0x65cba808
| sysTid=5830 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1707859064
| state=S schedstat=( 16917000 23230125 83 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42576bb0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=19 (AdWorker #6)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #5" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4250d2f0 self=0x65cba3b8
| sysTid=5829 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1707858848
| state=S schedstat=( 10773375 9319125 62 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x425195a0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (AdWorker #5)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #4" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x425093d8 self=0x65cb1a58
| sysTid=5826 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1750441672
| state=S schedstat=( 40946625 32669250 142 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x424f5bc8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (AdWorker #4)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #3" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x429ac658 self=0x6521bb48
| sysTid=5814 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1755337696
| state=S schedstat=( 14493750 10239000 56 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x429ac788> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (AdWorker #3)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #2" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424f29b8 self=0x65195788
| sysTid=5772 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1696160728
| state=S schedstat=( 187430250 69782625 291 ) utm=16 stm=2 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x424f2ae8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AdWorker #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Gservices" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424e3a80 self=0x64edc740
| sysTid=5771 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1698842416
| state=S schedstat=( 1592625 1721625 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
#00 pc 0001860c /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014b09 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 00014d71 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 0005ee2b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001e290 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004d411 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
#06 pc 000276a0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 0002b57c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#08 pc 0005fc31 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#09 pc 0005fc5b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#10 pc 000547d7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#12 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at com.google.android.gsf.g.run(SourceFile:85)

"Binder_4" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424e2ed0 self=0x64a1b3f0
| sysTid=5770 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1698841824
| state=S schedstat=( 20267625 11236125 111 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 0001770c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002a70d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 00017363 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b15d /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00011267 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 00046827 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010dcd /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#09 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AdWorker #1" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423b1128 self=0x68a93050
| sysTid=5767 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1688345192
| state=S schedstat=( 62938125 37317000 165 ) utm=4 stm=2 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x423b12c8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=11 (AdWorker #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423bb490 self=0x650da208
| sysTid=5750 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073913672
| state=S schedstat=( 21292125 11917500 115 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=1
#00 pc 0001770c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002a70d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 00017363 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b15d /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00011267 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 00046827 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010dcd /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#09 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d20258 self=0x64e6b008
| sysTid=5608 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1745234816
| state=S schedstat=( 24972000 17994375 149 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=1
#00 pc 0001770c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002a70d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 00017363 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b15d /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00011267 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 00046827 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010dcd /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#09 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d1ffe0 self=0x6831cfe8
| sysTid=5607 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1752326840
| state=S schedstat=( 29002125 17950500 143 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=3
#00 pc 0001770c /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002a70d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 00017363 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b15d /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00011267 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 00046827 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010dcd /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 0000e3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#09 pc 0000dac4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d1ced8 self=0x64e3b008
| sysTid=5606 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1757905496
| state=S schedstat=( 765375 6303375 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x419324d8> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:230)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d1cd80 self=0x64e3bb58
| sysTid=5605 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1750985800
| state=S schedstat=( 54320625 20621250 101 ) utm=5 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4191e610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d1cc18 self=0x6536b008
| sysTid=5604 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1759842776
| state=S schedstat=( 4781625 908250 51 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4191e538>
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Anyone experienced this issue? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I just ignored as @William said and I never got it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a rare exception I would not worry about it. Once you have been developing Android apps for a while you will see lots of these.

Ignore it and concentrate on the errors that repeat.

Comment: This is not a valid answer, basically using this logic all developers should avoid rare bugs.

Comment: @AndyRoid There are bugs within the Android framework that you as a developer are **unable** to resolve. Once you have been developing for a while you will learn which of these to ignore. By all means report them, but don't expect them to be fixed for the next release of your ap.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't hurt to find a workaround. For example I've worked with the MediaPlayer library a lot and I have encountered rare bugs in Samsungs custom firmware. Although it was a pain in the ass to find a fix I did, and that naturally involved looking deep in their source or even the NDK. Just because YOU may not be able to find a fix, doesn't mean that you should discourage other people from doing so.

Comment: Sure. You spend your resource where you find most value.